# How can I perform math on a pandas pivottable?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following df I have filtered from a CSV of financial data for stocks.

```
    ticker  comp_name   per_fisc_year   per_fisc_qtr    tot_revnu
47  A   AGILENT TECH    2006    4   4973.0
48  A   AGILENT TECH    2007    4   5420.0
58  A   AGILENT TECH    2006    1   1167.0
59  A   AGILENT TECH    2006    2   1239.0
60  A   AGILENT TECH    2006    3   1239.0
61  A   AGILENT TECH    2006    4   1328.0
62  A   AGILENT TECH    2007    1   1280.0
63  A   AGILENT TECH    2007    2   1320.0
64  A   AGILENT TECH    2007    3   1374.0
65  A   AGILENT TECH    2007    4   1446.0
```

I then need to ADD up all the Quarterly data to get annual with a Pivot Table.

```
mean_rev_table = pd.pivot_table(zacks_df_filter_1, values=['tot_revnu'],
                                index=['comp_name'],columns=['per_fisc_year'],
                                aggfunc=np.mean)

mean_rev_table[:5]
```

which gives me a nicely formatted table

```
                   tot_revnu
per_fisc_year   2006    2007
comp_name       
1800FLOWERS.COM 390.962667  290.26000
21ST CENTURY IN 550.114800  349.28200
24/7 KID DOC    0.857600    1.09520
24/7 REAL MEDIA 80.097200   57.66300
3COM CORP   409.215333  506.99238
```

Now I want to calc annual growth or just delta between 2006 and 2007 but I dont know how to reference the total Annual in the table (2006 and 2007).

I tried.

```
mean_rev_table['rev_growth']= mean_rev_df['2007']  - mean_rev_df['2006']
```

but I get a key error because I think it only recognizes tot_revnu as the column. I probably need to recreate the Pivot Table but not sure how to. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need remove `[]`for avoid `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
mean_rev_table=zacks_df_filter_1.pivot_table( 
                              values='tot_revnu', <-[] create MultiIndex
                              index='comp_name',
                              columns='per_fisc_year',aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Another solution is [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
mean_rev_table.columns = mean_rev_table.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Comment: Wow that was simple - Thanks so much @jezrael. I voted but not enough reputation points to upvote.

Comment: Hi Tek, you can still "accept" jezrael's answer by clicking the check mark above it since it solved your problem. It's like the ultimate upvote.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `groupby()` + `unstack()`:

```
mean_rev_table = (zacks_df_filter_1.groupby(['comp_name','per_fisc_year'])['tot_revnu']
                                   .sum()
                                   .unstack('per_fisc_year')
                                   .rename_axis(None, 1))
```

Result:

```
In [46]: mean_rev_table
Out[46]:
                2006     2007
comp_name
AGILENT TECH  9946.0  10840.0
```